# on Click over Slice in Pie Chart, Filter all records of that Slice of Pie Chart in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, events, charts, onclick, excel-interop

I want create a Pie Chart using Pivot Table data And OnClick over slice of Pie Chart, Filter all records in that Slice of Pie Chart in Pivot Table.My problem is I want Chart event Handling to work within the excel file without using browser based window. Basically I want to create Pivot Table within the Chart( just like chart within chart). I tried using **Google.visualization** google.visualization.events.addListener(source_visualization,event_name, handling_function) but it is browser based and i tried **Chartjs** even those are browser based. To my Findings, I think using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** is the Solution to my problem.

I was using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** nuget package as addon package to **EPPlus** Excel nuget package as ordinary excel nuget packages doesn't support Chart Event Handling only After using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Chart Events Works. First, to test if Chart Event Function is triggered I wrote a simple program that is onClick over chart, ConsoleWrite("Chart Click"). But the Function doesn't get called and program exitted.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using OfficeOpenXml;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Downloads\\ColumnGemBox.xlsx");
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Chart"] as Excel.Worksheet;
            Excel.ChartObjects chartObjects = worksheet.ChartObjects() as Excel.ChartObjects;
            Excel.ChartObject chartObject = (ChartObject)chartObjects.Item(1);

            // Handle chart events
            chartObject.Chart.MouseUp += new Excel.ChartEvents_MouseUpEventHandler(Chart_MouseUp);


            // Display Excel and wait for events
            excelApp.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    // Event handler for mouse click on the chart
    static void Chart_MouseUp(int button, int shift, int x, int y)
    {
        // Handle chart mouse click event here
        Console.WriteLine("Chart clicked!");
    }
}
```

Does Anyone know what is exact program here?

Comment: I think you should clarify whether you're working in Excel and you have added a Chart, using the Excel "Insert" menu?
Have you inserted a simple Chart or a Pivot Chart? Because with Pivot Charts, you do have the option to filter, but not directly on click as far as I know.

Comment: No, I have created data, pivot table and chart all using c# program only